# empty aws lambda child process execution detected on puresec's function-shield

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to use [puresec's function_shield](https://www.puresec.io/function-shield) to secure my service's lambdas.
For test purpose, I wrote a very basic function, which just call's `boto3.resource('dynamodb')` and exits.
The strange thing is that function_shield logs a child_process generation attempt:
`{"function_shield":true,"policy":"create_child_process","details":{"path":"/bin/sh"},"mode":"alert"}
{"function_shield":true,"policy":"create_child_process","details":{"path":"/bin/uname"},"mode":"alert"}`

I noticed that if I take the resource call away, the log goes together...
Shall I worry?
How can I determine if this call is being made from boto3 or my system is being compromised?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't malicious. Boto3 uses Python's built-in 'platform.system()' function to retrieve platform information. For some reason, the Python built-in function is invoking a shell process to run uname and get the data, instead of using more secure facilities to get the same data.

At the moment, until we resolve this issue, you can disable child process creation in FunctionShield before you call boto3.resource('dynamodb'), and then re-enable it right after.

```
function_shield.configure({
        "policy": {
            "create_child_process": "allow"
        }
    })
    boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    function_shield.configure({
        "policy": {
            "create_child_process": "alert"
        }
    })
```

For future reference, we opened a github repo for FunctionShield, where you can create issues: https://github.com/puresec/FunctionShield/